# Parsing Data Out Of TextBox? VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a project that reads a URL and then goes to the link and reads the data. Its a text hosting website (TextUploader.com) But when it downloads the site. I only want the data from the text that I have put there. When I download the Link and send it to the RichTextBox1 this  is what i get

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>'HPTjNRgUfG' | TextUploader.com</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="http://textuploader.com/favicon.ico">

    <meta property="og:title" content="HPTjNRgUfG" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://textuploader.com/5jx4u"/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="textuploader.com - HPTjNRgUfG"/>
    <meta property="og:description" content="Please call back later &lt;a href=&quot; http://philadelphiaexplorers.org/about-the-explorers-club/#annual &quot;&gt;a..."/>
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://textuploader.com/5jx4u"/>
                <!-- bootstrap framework css -->
    <link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.0/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">
    <!-- power tooltips -->
    <link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-powertip/1.1.0/jquery.powertip.css">

    <!-- main stylesheet -->
    <link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://textuploader.com/assets/css/beoro.css">
    <link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://textuploader.com/assets/css/tu_custom.css">

    <!--[if lte IE 8]><link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://textuploader.com/assets/css/ie8.css">
<![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 9]><link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://textuploader.com/assets/css/ie9.css">
<![endif]-->

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.6.2pre/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/respond.js/1.1.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.7/excanvas.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-36314765-1']);
        _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'textuploader.com']);
        _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
        (function() {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();
    </script>



            <link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/7.3/styles/default.min.css">
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/7.3/highlight.min.js"></script>
        <script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>

</head>

<body class="bg_c">

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=456470037742170";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<!-- main wrapper (without footer) -->
<div class="main-wrapper">
    <!-- top bar -->

    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="pull-right top-search">
                                    </div>


                <div id="fade-menu" class="pull-left">
                    <ul class="clearfix" id="mobile-nav">
                                                <li><a href="http://textuploader.com/">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://textuploader.com/discover">Discover</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://textuploader.com/help">Help</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://textuploader.com/developers">Developers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://textuploader.com/contact">Contact</a></li>

                        <li><a href='https://textuploader.com/profile'>My Account</a>
                                                    </li>



                    </ul>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- header -->
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span3">
                    <!-- <div class="main-logo"><a href="http://textuploader.com/"><img src="http://textuploader.com/assets/img/textuploader_logo.png" alt="TextUploader.com"></div> -->
                    <div class="main-logo"><a href='http://textuploader.com/'><img src="http://textuploader.com/assets/img/textuploader_logo.png" alt="TextUploader.com"></a></div>
                </div>
                <div class="span5">
                    <nav class="nav-icons">
                        <!-- small icons navigation -->
                    </nav>
                </div>
                <div class="span4">
                                        <div class="user-box">
                        <div class="user-box-inner">
                            <img src="//www.gravatar.com/avatar/d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e?s=80&r=g&d=mm" class="user-avatar img-avatar" alt="Gravatar"/>

                            <div class="user-info">
                                <a href="https://textuploader.com/register">Create an Account</a>                                <ul class="unstyled">
                                    <li><a href="https://textuploader.com/auth/login">Login</a></li>
                                    <li>&middot;</li>
                                    <li><a href="https://textuploader.com/auth/password/forgot">Password</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

        <!-- breadcrumbs -->
    <div class="container">
                <ul id="breadcrumbs">
            <li>
                <a href="http://textuploader.com/">
                    <i class="icon-home"></i>
                </a></li>

                                                <li><a href="http://textuploader.com/">Home</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="http://textuploader.com/5jx4u">textuploader.com/5jx4u</a></li>

            <li><span>Posted on: 11/16/15 1:59:00 AM UTC</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>


    <!-- main content -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12">
                <div class="w-box w-box-blue">
                    <div class="w-box-header"><h4>"HPTjNRgUfG" - Views: 2 &middot; Hits: 2 - Type: Public</h4></div>
                    <div class="w-box-content cnt_a ">


<div class="toolbar clearfix">
    <div class="pull-left">
        <div class="toolbar-icons clearfix">
            <div style="overflow:hidden;width:90px;float:left;">
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://textuploader.com/5jx4u" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count"
         data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>
</div>
<div style="overflow:hidden;width:90px;float:left;">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://textuploader.com/5jx4u">Tweet</a>
</div>
<div style="overflow:hidden;width:90px;float:left;">
    <div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium" data-annotation="none"
         data-href="http://textuploader.com/5jx4u"></div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>


        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pull-right">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn btn-mini" onClick="parent.location='http://textuploader.com/5jx4u/rev'; void(0);">Revisions (0)</button>
                                    <button class="btn btn-mini" onClick="parent.location='http://textuploader.com/contact'; void(0);">Report Abuse</button>
                    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<pre><code class='no-highlight'>Please call back later &lt;a href=&quot; http://philadelphiaexplorers.org/about-the-explorers-club/#annual &quot;&gt;accidently took 2 40 mg paxil&lt;/a&gt;  &quot;We need that flexibility,&quot; Fox said. &quot;When you pick your offensive line, not just for the season, but for game day, you have to pick them from the standpoint of having some flexibility. You&#039;ve got to have a swing guard/center, you&#039;ve got to have a swing tackle/guard, for the games.&quot;
 </code></pre>


                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>


    </div>

    <div class="footer_space"></div>
</div>
<!-- footer -->
<footer>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span8">
                <div>&copy; 2016 <a href="http://www.exsom.com" target="_blank">Exsom Group, LLC</a>. All Rights Reserved.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="span4">
                <ul class="unstyled">
<!--                    
<li><a href="https://tuarmor.com">TUArmor</a></li>
                    <li>&middot;</li>
-->
                    <li><a href="http://textuploader.com/terms-of-service">Terms of Service</a></li>
                    <li>&middot;</li>
                    <li><a href="http://textuploader.com/privacy">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                    <li>&middot;</li>
                    <li><a href="http://textuploader.com/dmca">DMCA</a></li>
            <li>&middot;</li>
                    <li><a href="http://status.textuploader.com/">System Status</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
<!-- Common JS -->
<!-- jQuery framework -->
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- bootstrap Framework plugins -->
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.0//js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- top menu -->
<script src="http://textuploader.com/assets/js/jquery.fademenu.js"></script>
<!-- top mobile menu -->
<script src="http://textuploader.com/assets/js/selectnav.min.js"></script>
<!-- actual width/height of hidden DOM elements -->
<script src="http://textuploader.com/assets/js/jquery.actual.min.js"></script>
<!-- jquery easing animations -->
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<!-- power tooltips -->
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-powertip/1.1.0/jquery.powertip-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
<!-- date library -->
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/1.7.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<!-- common functions -->
<script src="http://textuploader.com/assets/js/beoro_common.js"></script>

<!-- twitter button code -->
<script>!function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https';
        if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
            js = d.createElement(s);
            js.id = id;
            js.src = p + '://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }
    }(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>

<!-- +1 code -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var po = document.createElement('script');
        po.type = 'text/javascript';
        po.async = true;
        po.src = '//apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
    })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What I want is just the plaintext here:

```
<pre><code class='no-highlight'>Please call back later &lt;a href=&quot; http://philadelphiaexplorers.org/about-the-explorers-club/#annual &quot;&gt;accidently took 2 40 mg paxil&lt;/a&gt;  &quot;We need that flexibility,&quot; Fox said. &quot;When you pick your offensive line, not just for the season, but for game day, you have to pick them from the standpoint of having some flexibility. You&#039;ve got to have a swing guard/center, you&#039;ve got to have a swing tackle/guard, for the games.&quot;
     </code></pre>
```

How would I write a simple code to parse only the data Between the "

```
" and "
```

" Above?

Comment: Instead of showing us just the wrong result that you get, how about showing us the code that produced it?

Comment: Try some things... Look into HTML parsing

Answer (score 0):

You can grab it using `Regex` if you want.

**Tried & Tested**

```
 (?s)(<pre>.+?<\/pre>)
```

That above is the pattern that can be used. If you want to confirm please see [**that here.**](https://regex101.com/r/aY6qD9/1)

I didn't show you how this can be done in `.net` as you did not provide us with what you have tried. I could break down the pattern, but the above link does that already.